# Backend and Frontend on same port

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, frontend, backend

I have a ec2 Windows instance on AWS, which responds with a frontend on port 80. My backend is running on port 5000. Is there any way I can host both frontend and backend on same port without using any port on a client for the rest API?

Frontend:

```
www.example.com
```

Current Backend:

```
www.example.com:5000
```

What I'd like it to be:

```
www.example.com/backend/
```

How do I to write a single index.js or server.js file for both Backend and Frontend routes?

Comment: You’re open to use a Nginx reversed proxy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, it's trivial to host both on the same port(s), it's just a question of routing.

For example, using `express.js` and having static files (CSS, images, HTML, etc) in a folder named `public`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/', express.static('public'))
app.get('/backend', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(80, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 80!'))
```

If you make a file `public/index.html`:

```
<html>HI</html>
```

Then you can get it (the "frontend") by running `curl 'localhost:80/'`:

```
$ curl 'localhost:80/'
<html>HI</html>
$
```

You can also access your 'backend':

```
$ curl 'localhost:80/backend'
Hello World!
$
```

Answer (score 16):

#### I recommend you to separate your service Endpoints in [Subdomains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)

> ## Service Endpoint
>
> The endpoint is a connection point where HTML files or active server pages are exposed. Endpoints provide information needed to address a Web service endpoint. The endpoint provides a reference or specification that is used to define a group or family of message addressing properties and give end-to-end message characteristics, such as references for the source and destination of endpoints, and the identity of messages to allow for uniform addressing of "independent" messages. The endpoint can be a PC, PDA, or point-of-sale terminal **Reference:** [Definition of service endpoint](http://www.ehow.com/info_12212371_definition-service-endpoint.html).

### For your Frontend endpoint the recommended subdomain is:

- http://`www`.example.com
- http://example.com
  *For this case you have to redirect to subdomain `www`*

### For your Backend endpoint you can use whatever you want, but the recommended subdomains for Backend are:

- http://`api`.example.com (The most used)
- http://`backend`.example.com

### So, in your case the recommendations are:

- Frontend: http://www.example.com
- Backend:  http://api.example.com

You can accomplish that using either a Reverse Proxy like [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or getting the Subdomain from the request object in NodeJs.

> **Nginx** is a web server which can also be used as a reverse proxy, load balancer, and HTTP cache. The software was created by Igor Sysoev and first publicly released in 2004. A company of the same name was founded in 2011 to provide support.

## First approach

[Using Nginx as HTTP load balancer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

**You can configure Nginx to balance the requests to your server as follow:**

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server localhost:5000;
    }

    upstream frontend {
        server localhost;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name api.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
        }
    }
}
```

## Second approach

Use [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) to get the subdomain from request object.

[req.subdomains](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.subdomains)

> An array of subdomains in the domain name of the request.

**Documentation:**

```
// Host: "tobi.ferrets.example.com"
req.subdomains
// => ["ferrets", "tobi"]
```

In your case your possible subdomains are: `www` or `api`

```
// Host: "www.example.com"
req.subdomains
// => ["www"]
```

Or

```
// Host: "api.example.com"
req.subdomains
// => ["api"]
```

This is how you have to process the request within your `server.js`

```
var subDomain = req.subdomains[0];
 
if (subdomain === 'api') {
    processBackendRequest();
} else {
    processFrontendRequest();
}
```

Comment: I too would prefer this , but how to do this on a local network ? I want to serve flask based REST api on subdomain.hostname.local and vuejs frontend on hostname.local

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to prevent having to specify a port number is use post 80 for HTTP, or 443 for HTTPS.

If you're running IIS you can have your front end running as a website called "example.com", and then under that website have another "application" called "backend".

All HTTP requests for www.example.com would go to the root website. Requests to www.example.com/backend would route to the "backend" application under the example.com website.

ServerFault may be a more appropriate place to ask IIS questions however.

Comment: To note: I've defaulted to IIS, as you mentioned Windows. May be best clarifying the actual hosting software used.